# Running react native app in Visual studio emulator for android

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, android-gradle-plugin, visual-studio-emulator

I am beginner of React-Native. I have Visual studio emulator for Android.can someone tell me how to run react native app in that?I added Visual Studio Emulator as External Tools. I followed (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/07/20/using-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-from-android-studio-or-eclipse-with-adt/) link to add Visual Studio emulator with Android Studio.

1.I tried building the project using 'react-native run-android' which ends with some build error. "Execution failed for task:'app:processGoogle services' No matching client found"

2. I tried "Gradlew build" which gave me the same error
3. I cleared the cache using cd android && ./gradlew clean
4. I tried "gradlew cleanBuildCache" but no use

am i doing something wrong? or how can i run React native app in Visual studio emulator for Android.Thanks

Comment: do you have `adb` command to check if your emulator is connected by typing `adb devices` in `cmd`?

Comment: I am able to the see the connected devices. Then when i try to run react-native run-android. it is giving me build error..

Comment: what error that you see? can you screenshot the error?

Comment: After a lot of clean and clear cache build..the build was successful.but i am getting Error type3 Error: Activity class {com.projectname/com.projectname.MainActivity} does not exist.

Comment: what command do you use when creating RN app? `react-native-cli` or `create-react-native-app`?

Comment: I just ran react-native run-android.

Comment: I checked the package name in MainActivity.java,AndroidManifest.xml,build.gradle and MainApplication.java. The package name is same in all 4 files

Comment: its difficult to find a problem about your issue without knowing the `command` how did you build the app of React Native

Comment: I have React Native App which runs perfectly in Android Studio and Android simulator. but if i want to use Android Studio emulator..I need to turn off the VM. I have docker also running in my machine.so i f i turn off VM.i cant use Docker. So i started using Visual Studio Emulator for Android. I moved to my Project directory and ran react-native run-android comment. earlier it gave me some build errors. so i did cd android and ran gradlew clean and cleanbuildcache now my errors were gone. but still not able to launch my app in VS Emulator.Do i need to run some other comments. pls help me .